# Multi Linux and one Windows bootable in one HDD

Tags: linux, windows, uefi, bootable

How do we have multi Linux and one Windows bootable OS in one UEFI system HDD with the option which one to boot at PC startup?(shown in step by step instructive explanations)?

Comment: I'm using rEFind for that purpose.  Roderick W. Smith gives plenty of explanations on his site: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: I just use grub. But have to make sure Windows fast start up is off, or that Windows does not have other issues like needing chkdsk. Then I boot directly from UEFI to fix Windows. Last install will be default boot loader in UEFI and in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.